# Is it possible to divine what events a SWF might call?

Tags: javascript, flash, decompiling

A bit of back story:

I have a flash video player in SWF form, no FLA. It plays videos, as you might expect, by passing in a URL as a parameter. This works great.

However, now the customer wants to trigger an action when the video ends. Problem is, I don't have any documentation, sources, or anything else that would help me determine what functions, if any, the SWF calls on video completion.

I have no idea whether this is a canned project or a file developed in house, I have no idea if the source FLA still exists, and the customer *really* likes it, so unfortunately changing it to something else is not really an option.

So, my question: Is there some debugging technique I can use to determine if it is trying to call a javascript function? I tried decompiling it using [this flash decompiler](http://code.google.com/p/flash-decompiler), but it did not yield any meaningful results.

I know this question is frustratingly vague, but believe me, it's as vague for me as it is for you :(

(Oh, and they want it done by the end of the day. Sigh.)

Comment: If you can make it so I can download the swf, I can take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by replacing the player. The client liked the old one, but preferred having the required functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can do anything if the original flash file wasn't made to call a specific javascript function. Flash can call javascript functions, but if it wasn't implemented in the fla, there is nothing you can do on the javascript side. Maybe your best option would be to decompile it and recompile it by adding a piece of code that calls a javascript functions once the video ends.

Comment: I know that I'm fairly SOL if it doesn't call the javascript, but I don't know if it does or not. That's the point of the question.